# How to select all content between two of the same tags?

Tags: jquery, html

[A similar question was asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481076/jquery-how-to-select-all-content-between-two-tags), but I'm looking for a jQuery solution using only the html below (ie. no classes or id attributes):

```
<h2>Foo</h2>
<p>asdf</p>
<ul><li>asdf</li></ul>
<p>asdf</p>
<h2>Bar</h2>
<p>asdf</p>
<p>asdf</p>
<h2>Baz</h2>
<p>asdf</p>
<p>asdf</p>
```

I'd like to use some jQuery like:

```
$('h2').afterButBeforeNext('h2').doSomething();
```

This should:

- select all the sibling elements after the specified element, but before the next occurrence of the specified element.
- if there is no end element, then select all the elements underneath it.

Comment: What do you want to do with that elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest solution using core jQuery functions:

```
$('h2').nextUntil('h2').doSomething();
```

[Jonathan Snook](http://snook.ca/) pointed me to the jQuery 1.4 function that solves this:

- [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

Check out it's sibling functions:

- [prevUntil](http://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/)
- [parentsUntil](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/)

Inspired by:

- [nextAll](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)
- [prevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)

Answer (score 6):

The prev selector should be able to do this: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/siblings#prevsiblings

```
$("h2 ~ *:not(h2)").doSomething();
```

You still need some sort of id or attribute to select just one single h2 element.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
function selectBetween(node1,node2,parent)
{
    var p = $(parent);
    var n1 = p.find(node1);
    var n2 = p.find(node2);
    var results = [];
    var start = false;
    var end = false;
    p.children().each(function()
    {
        if(!start && !end)
        {
            if($(this) === n1)
            {
                start = true;
            }
            results.push(this);
            if($(this) === n2)
            {
                end = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    });
    return results;
}
var between = selectBetween($(parent).find('h2:first'), $(parent).find('h2:last'), parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrate, the h2 tag content turns red and the p, ul tag content turns green:

```
$('#container').children().each(function(){
    if(this.nodeName == 'H2'){
        $(this).css('color','red');
        $(this).nextAll().each(function(){
            if(this.nodeName != 'H2'){
                $(this).css('color','green');
            }
        });        
        return false; //exit here to only process the nodes between the first H2 and second H2 found.
    }
});
```

*Note that I'm assuming a #container div not shown in your example. If there is no container use $(body).children().*

Comment: No problem, and you're right. I upvoted the accepted answer - it was well deserved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var name = "h2";
$(name).each(function() {
    var siblings = [], sibling=this.nextSibling;
    while (sibling && sibling.nodeName.toLowerCase() != name) {
        siblings.push(sibling);
        sibling = sibling.nextSibling;
    }
    // siblings now contains an array of sibling elements that are not h2
});
```