# text between anchor elements in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a paragraph with text and anchors.

Given an anchor `$myAnchor` within the paragraph, I can get the immediately following one:

> `$nextAnchor = $myAnchor.next('a');`

How do I get the text/HTML between these two anchors?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481076/jquery-how-to-select-all-content-between-two-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$myAnchor[0].nextSibling.nodeValue
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/3Xp6G/1/

So, `nextSibling` will give you a reference to the next sibling node (which is a Text node), and then `nodeValue` will return the text-content of that Text node.

Btw `[0]` is required after `$myAnchor` because `nextSibling` is a property of DOM nodes, not jQuery objects, and `[0]` returns the first DOM element from the jQuery object.

You can also use `.trim()` at the end to get rid of the useless white-space (if there is any).

Comment: Thanks. Is this low-level solution cross-browser?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: misunderstood question.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/RkEwR/

Use .contents()

Comment: This returns the text of the anchor, not the text between two anchors

Answer (score 0):

To get the text between 2 anchors o can do something like this.

```
var a1 = $('#anchor1');
var a2 = $('#anchor2');

var contents = a1.parent().contents();

var s, e;
for(var i = 0; i<contents.length; i++){
    if($(contents[i]).is(a1)){
        s = i 
    }
    if($(contents[i]).is(a2)){
        e = i
    }
}

var text = contents.slice(s + 1,e).text().trim();
```

If you know that there is only one element in betewwen u can use the `nextSibling` method described.