# Jquery change text between two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change text between two elements using JQuery, but I don't have any idea !

for example:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='ch1'>
    This text must be changed !!!
<input type='checkbox' name='ch2'>
```

Also, I don't have any control over this Html code, so I can't add any IDs or tags.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can call [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) on the parent element to obtain its child text nodes, then use [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) with [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to locate the text nodes you want to remove. From there on, [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) will allow you to add the new content:

```
var ch1 = $("input:checkbox[name=ch1]"),
    ch2 = $("input:checkbox[name=ch2]"),
    contents = ch1.parent().contents();
contents.slice(contents.index(ch1) + 1, contents.index(ch2)).remove();
ch1.after("The text was changed.");
```

You can test it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aHQth/).

Answer (score 2):

You use js `replace` function to substitute the text you want to replace
Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/yangchenyun/8zFFc/

Here is the code

```
var replacedText = $('input[name=ch1]').parent().html().replace('This text must change !!!', 'replaced text');

$('input[name=ch1]').parent().html(replacedText);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem with your solution is using specific text ('This text must change !!!'). I don't know the text that must change.

Answer (score 0):

Are the 2 inputs in a bigger container div? Then you could se-set that divs innerHTML without the text inbetween

Answer (score 0):

Can you ad a span like this?

```
<input type='checkbox' name='ch1'>
<span id="change"> This text must change !!!</span>
<input type='checkbox' name='ch2'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try `contents()` to select the text node next to the checkbox you want and remove it.

However, I think it might not work in IE6/7.

try this

```
$(function(){
$('input:checkbox').parents().contents()
```

`.filter( function(index){return (this.nodeType === 3 && $('input:checkbox').parents().contents().eq(index-1).attr('name') === 'ch1' ); }).remove();
    });`

[Check out the result here](http://jsfiddle.net/maxisam/4GbVN/3/)

Answer (score 0):

this might be helpful for you:

http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Answer (score 0):

Using Vanilla JS:

```js
document.getElementsByName('ch1')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = "changed!"
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' name='ch1'>
    This text must be changed !!!
<input type='checkbox' name='ch2'>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert(getAllBetween("input#ch1","input#ch2"));
});

function getAllBetween(firstEl,lastEl) {
    var firstElement = $(firstEl); // First Element
    var lastElement = $(lastEl); // Last Element
    var collection = new Array(); // Collection of Elements
    collection.push(firstElement); // Add First Element to Collection
    $(firstEl).nextAll().each(function(){ // Traverse all siblings
        var siblingID  = $(this).attr("id"); // Get Sibling ID
        if (siblingID != $(lastElement).attr("id")) { // If Sib is not LastElement
                collection.push($(this)); // Add Sibling to Collection
        } else { // Else, if Sib is LastElement
                return false; // Break Loop
        }
    });         
    return collection; // Return Collection
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481076/jquery-how-to-select-all-content-between-two-tags same content

Answer (score -2):

You can use paragraph

for the text as below

```
<input type='checkbox' name='ch1'>
<p id="change_text"> This text must change !!!</p>
<input type='checkbox' name='ch2'>
```

in jquery use

```
$("#change_text").html(" Your text here ");
```

Comment: I don't have control over HTML code, therefore I can't add new tag!!