# XPath select text after specific node

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping

```
<h3>Contact Information</h3> To Apply : Please send your CV and cover
letter to DAIIDEANEW2012@gmail.com include Grants Manager - Jalalabad
in the subject line of the application.
```

How can I select text after above node? I have piece of following code but this is not working.

```
$email = $xmlPageXPath->query('//*[preceding-sibling::h3[text()="Contact Information"]]');
$tag="contactinformation";
$XML.=createXMLtags($tag,nodelist2string($email));
```

Comment: Hum I think your HTML was rendered instead being displayed as a code...

Comment: Fixed it, please use for spaces before code to format it correctly. Is this code inside another node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath you tried will return only elements, excluding text node which you seems interested in :

```
//*[preceding-sibling::h3[text()="Contact Information"]]
```

You can use `text()` instead, to select text nodes, for example :

```
//text()[preceding-sibling::h3[.="Contact Information"]]
```

Comment: This piece of code is working '//text()[preceding::h3[.="Contact Information"]]' but it fetch the rest of page as well. I want to stop it when the '<div class="clr">' reach. If I add preceding-sibling then it fetch half text because the text is copied from word and has html tags.

Comment: Check Jens Erat comment. Adding criteria `and following:div[@class="clr"]` seems will do the trick. If that isn't what you're looking for, I'd suggest to edit the question (or better yet, post new one), and include sample html that demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the header, and return the first following text node.

```
//h3[.="Contact Information"]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

If there's something that wraps those two tags, eg. like in

```
<div>
  <h3>Contact Information</h3> To Apply : Please send your CV and cover
  letter to DAIIDEANEW2012@gmail.com include Grants Manager - Jalalabad
  in the subject line of the application.
</div>
```

it might be more reasonable to query this div and the direct text children:

```
//div[h3="Contact Information"]/text()
```

Comment: This part of text is copy and paste from word which means several tags are carried inside text. for example <table>. Is it possible to have all text until the '<div class="clr">' reach?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. [Here I answered a similar question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785763/how-to-get-all-text-nodes-value-between-span-nodes/14786549#14786549) It should be rather easy to apply the pattern to your problem.

Comment: I saw the topic but couldn't apply it. This piece of code is working '//text()[preceding::h3[.="Contact Information"]]' but it fetch the rest of page as well. I want to stop it when the '<div class="clr">' reach. Thanks

Comment: All you have to do is testing if the `<div>` is following the text node: `//text()[preceding::h3[.="Contact Information"] and following:div[@class="clr"]]`.

Comment: This fixed `//text()[preceding::h3[.="Contact Information"] and following::h3[text()="General"]]`

Comment: Just realized there is a typo in the query, it should be `following::div` (two colons).