# How to obtain the text content between two anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `html` content as shown below.Is there any way to obtain  using `Jquery`  the text in between the two `anchor` tags without wrapping any `div` or `span` tags around the text named "user1" .I need the output as "user1". Could someone please help me.

```
<div class="test 1">
           <input id="field1" type="hidden" value="terminal">
           <a class="Prev" title="prevoius" href="#">previous</a>
           User1 
           <a class="btnNext" title="next" href="#">next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8118165/1920232

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var theText = $('.Prev')[0].nextSibling.textContent || $('.Prev')[0].nextSibling.innerText;
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aBm7C/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Following code would give you the desired text.

```
var ch1 = $("a[class=Prev]");
var ch2 = $("a[class=btnNext]");
var contents = ch1.parent().contents();
contents.slice(contents.index(ch1) + 1, contents.index(ch2)).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://api.jquery.com/contents/

*contents* returns the "children of each element in the set of matched elements, *including text and comment nodes*". It should return four children: input, a, text, a.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `nextUntil`.

http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/