# Change text between tags with javascript

Tags: javascript, text, innerhtml

I'd like to change some text that is between those tags :

```
<div id=thing>
<a href=link></a>texttochangehere<a href=link2></a>
</div>
```

But without changing the links. I tried replacing only the part I want with innerHTML and substring, but it seems to unlink the  tags that another script uses.

Comment: [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) vs. [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML). See also [`innerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8118165/2256325

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are at least two ways to achieve your goal:

1. String replacement and HTML parsing (using [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML))
2. DOM manipulation setting the text node (using [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent))

```
var div = document.getElementById('thing');

// replace text in HTML string:
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace('texttochangehere','changedtext');

// manipulating text node:
for(var node of div.childNodes){
    if(node.nodeType == 3 && node.textContent == 'texttochangehere')
        node.textContent = 'changedtext';
}
```

Comment: In lieu of the magic number `3`, we can also use the equivalent constant `Node.TEXT_NODE`, which might improve readability. (See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType), [DOM Standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-node-nodetype%E2%91%A0))