# applying CSS styling between selected headers

Tags: html, css

I would like to select elements between h1 tags. For example, I would like to apply a style to all p between the h1#bap and the next h1, while not changing the style at any other places.

No other tags should be added (otherwise, it'd be too easy :) ).

Can't use any nth-sibiling as elements between headers can be trillions.

Obviously, I may want to apply style between other headers as well (between specific h2,...).

```
<h1 id="bap">bap</h1>
  <p>foo bap</p>
  <p>foo bap 1</p>
  <p>foo bap 2</p>
  <p>foo bap 3</p>
  <p>foo bap 4</p>
  <div>defoo bap</div>
<h1 id="random-bor">random bor</h1>
  <p>balibom</>p
```

Comment: If you have trillions of elements on your page, you have a much bigger problem on your hands :)

Comment: Could you clarify upon what you actually want to select? perhaps you could put a note inside the elements you want to select in your code.

Comment: Sternbeanrainbowlabs, I will think about that next time I ask a question on the web! : I will comment, or, better, display is needed. For now, you can see result in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a lesser know selector formally called the Sibling combinator (well, I think that's it's name anyway!)

Using this syntax, you can select all p elements after `<h1 id="bap">bap</h1>`:

```
#bap ~ p { color: red; }
```

Unfortunately, this selects all paragraph elements after `<h1 id="random-bor">random bor</h1>`
 too, but this can be overcome by resetting the styles of those paragraph elements like such:

```
#random-bor ~ p { color: black; }
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RvDnN/)

This works in every modern browser, unfortunately it doesn't work in IE6, if that's an issue then a jQuery solution would probably be best.

Comment: It's called the general sibling combinator (or following-sibling combinator). There are two sibling combinators; the other is the adjacent (or next-sibling) combinator `+`.

Comment: No problem, I find a demo also helps when trying to explain/illustrate :)

Answer (score 1):

```
h1#bap + p{color:red}​
```

This works for the first p tag. Need to find the way to apply for all the tags. This is what I got for now

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest to add some `<div>`s around each section, until I read the bit where you said no other tags should be added.

You can't do it with css alone, but you could use some JavaScript to implement this algorithm:

1. Loop through all the elements of the page.
2. When you see a `<h1>`, remember it's id.
3. For every `<p>`, give it a class that corresponds to the last `<h1>`'s id.

You should end up with something like this, which you should be able to style easily with css.

```
<h1 id="bap">bap</h1>
  <p class="bap">foo bap</p>
  <p class="bap">foo bap 1</p>
  <p class="bap">foo bap 2</p>
  <p class="bap">foo bap 3</p>
  <p class="bap">foo bap 4</p>
  <div>defoo bap</div>
<h1 id="random-bor">random bor</h1>
  <p class="random-bor">balibom</>p
```

Then you can style things like this:

```
p.bap {}
p.random-bor {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can only be done with javascript, if you're using jquery it would look like

```
$('h1#bap').nextUntil("h1#random-bor",'p').css('background','red');
```

**Edit:**

[How to select all content between two tags in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481076/jquery-how-to-select-all-content-between-two-tags)

this explains exactly what you would like to have done

**Edit2:**

there is also a jquery function
http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Comment: Yes, it can only be done with jQuery, but this is just `h1 ~ p` and so it's not correct.

Comment: Wouldn't jQuery be noticeably slower on a large amount of elements?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs well i tested jqueries nextUntil, and it doesnt seem to affect performance at all tbh

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs: Anything is slower on a large amount of elements.

Comment: @BoltClock That is very true. Wouldn't css (if a solution can be found) be much faster than jQuery?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs: Yeah, CSS is usually faster than jQuery for styling purposes.