# Select all HTML between 2 tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery - How to select all content between two tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481076/jquery-how-to-select-all-content-between-two-tags)

Suppose I have some HTML, e.g.:

```
<div>
<span>
<a>Link</a>
</span>
<p id="start">Foo</p>
<!-- loads of HTML goes here -->
<img src="bar.png" />
<form id="end">
<input type="text" />
</form>
</div>
```

Now suppose I want to select everything between the `<p>` and the `</form>`, and put it into a string. How would I do that (note that I won't necessarily know what is between the 2 tags? JQuery answers are welcome.

Comment: Use an HTML parser, regexes, etc.

Comment: What have you tried? Is the HTML part of a document fragment, or is it still just a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) gets immediate sibling until the given selector

```
​$('#start').nextUntil('form')​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```