# How can I wrap each element and all its siblings before the next occurrence of the same element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, siblings, wrapall

I've got some markup that's similar to the following:

```html
<h3>A Heading</h3>
<p>Here is a paragraph.</p>

<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
</ul>

<blockquote>Here's some other block-level element</blockquote>

<h3>The Wrapping Should Stop Before This Heading, but a Second One Should Begin</h3>
<ol>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
</ol>

<p>Notice the varying block-level elements? It probably doesn't make any difference.</p>
```

I want to wrap each `h3` and everything up to, but not including, the next `h3` in a single `div`.

The result should be:

```html
<div>
  <h3>A Heading</h3>
  <p>Here is a paragraph.</p>

  <ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
  </ul>

  <blockquote>Here's some other block-level element</blockquote>
</div>

<div>
  <h3>The Wrapping Should Stop Before This Heading, but a Second One Should Begin</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
  </ol>

  <p>Notice the varying block-level elements? It probably doesn't make any difference.</p>
</div>
```

I've found similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/481076). It uses a combination of `.nextUntil()` and `.andSelf()` (or `.addBack()` once my edit is approved), but this would wrap the `h3`s and the content between in *separate* `div`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) was the missing link.

```
$('h3').nextUntil('h3').addBack().wrapAll('<div>');
```

Answer (score 3):

You need the `:first` selector otherwise you will wrap all the content not just the first `h3`to 2nd `h3`

`$('h3:first').nextUntil('h3').addBack().wrapAll('<div>');`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qkPWU/)

Comment: That's right. For my particular use case I was getting them all, but that wasn't stated in the question for simplicity's sake.