# check if user cursor between two tokens in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to design a special textarea which often has blocks of code. These code blocks are denoted by two ``` tokens, eg:

````
```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  name = raw_input("what's your name? ")
  print("Hello, {}!".format(name))
```
````

I want two events to happen: *when a user's cursor is in between fenced code blocks*, and *when a user's cursor leaves the fenced code blocks*.

When a user enters a code block, I want to enable code editting like converting the tab button to four spaces. When they leave the code block, I want to make an ajax call to render it.

My main problem is trying to find whether the user's cursor is in one of these fenced code blocks and when their cursor leaves code blocks. How would this be handled in an efficient manner?

Comment: No answer for you but this may be useful: http://javascript.nwbox.com/cursor_position/

Comment: @Moob That was neat. I never knew about .selectionStart

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I think it will get you at least 90% there.

*Reference:* [How to select all content between two tags in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481076/how-to-select-all-content-between-two-tags-in-jquery)

**Targeting the code blocks:**

````
$("*:contains('```')").eq(0)
                      .nextUntil("*:contains('```')")
                      .andSelf()
                      .wrap("<div id='mouse-box'></div>");
````

If you have multiple of these boxes, you may want to scrap eq() for something that lets you select even/odd/nth depending on the circumstances.

**Mouse Events**

```
$("#mouse-box").mouseenter(function(){
    // do something
});

$("#mouse-box").mouseleave(function(){
    // do something else
});
```

Not sure the best mouse handling, but I don't think that was your main challenge.