# How to select siblings between 2 tags of same class using CSS

Tags: html, css, element, siblings

I have a bunch of table rows `<tr></tr>`

Few of which are of `class = "node"`

Only one of the `tr.node` will be of `class = "active"`

```
<tr class="node">...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr class="node">...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr class="node active">...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr class="node">...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr class="node">...</tr>
```

I want to select all the `<tr>`'s from `tr.node.active` to next `tr.node` excluding the `tr.node`'s themselves.

This question uses jquery 
[How to select all content between two tags in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481076/how-to-select-all-content-between-two-tags-in-jquery)

Is there any way of doing this using CSS only, as using javascript would be difficult in the given scenario of my project?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But as I said using javascript is hard if not possible. Can I use css to do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use CSS3 `~` to selecting all sibling of element.

```css
tr.node.active ~ tr {
    color: red;
}

tr.node.active ~ tr.node,
tr.node.active ~ tr.node ~ tr {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="node"><td>node</td></tr>
    <tr><td>tr</td></tr>
    <tr><td>tr</td></tr>
    <tr class="node active"><td>node active</td></tr>
    <tr><td>tr</td></tr>
    <tr><td>tr</td></tr>
    <tr><td>tr</td></tr>
    <tr><td>tr</td></tr>
    <tr><td>tr</td></tr>
    <tr class="node"><td>node</td></tr>
    <tr><td>tr</td></tr>
    <tr><td>tr</td></tr>
    <tr><td>tr</td></tr>
    <tr class="node"><td>node</td></tr>
</table>
```